# Unable to show the div using jquery on selecting particular option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

This is in the head tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is in the body

```
<select name="product" id="product">
<option value="1">Select Your Product</option>    
<option value="2">On Grid</option>
<option value="3">Off Grid</option>
<option value="4">Solar Water Pump [Irrigation]</option>    
<option value="5">Solar Water Heater </option>    
<option value="6">Online UPS </option>    
<option value="7">Residential UPS</option>
<option value="8">Generator Replacement Lifts Inverter </option>
<option value="9">Energy Efficient LED'S </option>
<option value="10">Powerplant IMC Leizning with ESCOMs</option>
<option value="11">Online UPS Installation </option> 
    </select>
 <input type="file" name="file_attach[]"  />
```

this is script which i kept outside the body

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#product").change(function() {

      if ($("#product option[value='2']").attr('selected')) {
         $('.file_attach').css('display','block');

      }
        else{
        $('.file_attach').css('display','none');
        }
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

When I select a question it is hidden.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val) to get the selected value

```
$("#product").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "2") {
        $('.file_attach').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.file_attach').css('display', 'none'); 
    }
});
```

And add the class to element

```
<input type="file" name="file_attach[]" class="file_attach" />
```

```js
$("#product").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "2") {
    $('.file_attach').css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $('.file_attach').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
.file_attach {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="product" id="product">
    <option value="1">Select Your Product</option>    
    <option value="2">On Grid</option>
    <option value="3">Off Grid</option>
    <option value="4">Solar Water Pump [Irrigation]</option>    
    <option value="5">Solar Water Heater </option>    
    <option value="6">Online UPS </option>    
    <option value="7">Residential UPS</option>
    <option value="8">Generator Replacement Lifts Inverter </option>
    <option value="9">Energy Efficient LED'S </option>
    <option value="10">Powerplant IMC Leizning with ESCOMs</option>
    <option value="11">Online UPS Installation </option> 
</select>
<input type="file" name="file_attach[]" class="file_attach" />
```

Comment: how to add css to input type = file

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class to the input field:

```
<input type="file" name="file_attach[]" class="file_attach" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```html
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



            <select name="product" id="product">
    <option value="1">Select Your Product</option>    
    <option value="2">On Grid</option>
    <option value="3">Off Grid</option>
    <option value="4">Solar Water Pump [Irrigation]</option>    
    <option value="5">Solar Water Heater </option>    
    <option value="6">Online UPS </option>    
    <option value="7">Residential UPS</option>
    <option value="8">Generator Replacement Lifts Inverter </option>
    <option value="9">Energy Efficient LED'S </option>
    <option value="10">Powerplant IMC Leizning with ESCOMs</option>
    <option value="11">Online UPS Installation </option> 
        </select>
     <input type="file" name="file_attach[]" class="file_attach" />



          <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#product").change(function() {
           
          if ($("#product").val() == "2") {
             $('.file_attach').css('display','block');
              
          }
            else{
            $('.file_attach').css('display','none');
            }
        }); 
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

3 changes:

1. Use `.val()` function to get value of a select element
2. Attach the `file_attach` class to the input element
3. Hide the input initially.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#product").change(function() {
    if ($("#product").val() === "2") {
      $('.file_attach').css('display', 'block');

    } else {
      $('.file_attach').css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="product" id="product">
<option value="1">Select Your Product</option>    
<option value="2">On Grid</option>
<option value="3">Off Grid</option>
<option value="4">Solar Water Pump [Irrigation]</option>    
<option value="5">Solar Water Heater </option>    
<option value="6">Online UPS </option>    
<option value="7">Residential UPS</option>
<option value="8">Generator Replacement Lifts Inverter </option>
<option value="9">Energy Efficient LED'S </option>
<option value="10">Powerplant IMC Leizning with ESCOMs</option>
<option value="11">Online UPS Installation </option> 
    </select>
<input type="file" class="file_attach" style="display:none" name="file_attach[]" />
```